# Как сделать фон из случайно расположенных фигур SVG?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Есть сайт с разметкой, на сайте есть некоторые элементы `div` с заданным `id` и определённым цветом фона.

```
<div id="id1" style="background-color: pink">Some content</div>
```

Необходимо написать скрипт, который между содержанием блока и его фоном разместит случайным образом набор фигур `SVG`.

Сами фигуры задаются заранее, скрипт располагает клоны фигур в разные места фона случайным образом, при этом немного варьируется угол поворота и масштаб фигуры.

Сами фигуры должны не сильно выделяться на фоне `div` но при этом что бы были видны.

Зачем это нужно - разнообразить и сделать более живыми фоны на уже имеющемся сайте.

Так как сайт уже есть, то нужно сделать так что бы работа скрипта не нарушала существующую разметку сайта.

Answer (score 5):

```js
/* Сначала создаём шаблоны фигур, которые мы будем клонировать в разные места холста */

var figures = `<path id="romb" stroke-width="3"  d="M -7 0 L 0 10 L 7 0 L 0 -10 Z" density="1.3"></path>
                <circle id="circle" stroke-width="3"  cx="0" cy="0" r="6" density="1.3"></circle>
                <path id="heart" density="1" stroke-width="3" d="m 0,0 c 11.8877244,-5.12802 6.8762304,-15.0345 0,-10.2561 -6.8762331,-4.7784 -11.8877253,5.12808 0,10.2561 z"></path>
                <path id="spiral" density="1" stroke-width="2" d="m 0,0 c 0.355148,0.54541 -0.5599783,0.74782 -0.9064997,0.59028 -0.9390516,-0.42691 -0.830818,-1.72238 -0.2740569,-2.40328 0.9959151,-1.21796 2.8657886,-0.99025 3.9000576,0.0422 1.517831,1.5151 1.15801,4.026 -0.358387,5.39683 -2.021118,1.8271 -5.1923651,1.32954 -6.8936142,-0.6746 -2.1408484,-2.52202 -1.5030616,-6.3617 0.9908296,-8.3904 3.0204365,-2.45703 7.5326986,-1.67774 9.8871716,1.30705 2.774666,3.51748 1.85316,8.70476 -1.623273,11.38395 -4.013679,3.09324 -9.8775083,2.02907 -12.8807287,-1.93949 -3.4124499,-4.50933 -2.20530414,-11.05076 2.2557161,-14.37751 5.0045905,-3.73211 12.2243596,-2.38179 15.8742866,2.57194 4.05211,5.49958 2.558467,13.39823 -2.888159,17.37106"></path>`;

/* Эту разметку мы добавим в результирующий SVG код в раздел defs. 

Используем кастомный атрибут density у этих фигур, 
через него будет рассчитываться плотность (количество) фигур на выходе. 
Величина density это количество фигур на квадратные 100 пикселей.*/

/* основная функция выполняющая обработку */
function GenerateBack(elementId, figures) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  var width = element.clientWidth;
  var height = element.clientHeight;

  space = width * height;

  var svg = document.createElement("svg");

  svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
  svg.setAttribute("xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");

  svg.style.width = width + "px";
  svg.style.height = height + "px";

  svg.setAttribute("width", width);
  svg.setAttribute("height", height);

  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `0 0 ${width} ${height}`);

  /* получаем цвет блока */
  var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);

  svg.style.backgroundColor = computedStyle.backgroundColor;

  /* Вычисляем слабо контрасный цвет для контуров фигур */
  var color = MoveColor(computedStyle.backgroundColor);

  /* вставляем в SVG полотно блок определения фигур */
  var defs = document.createElement("defs");
  defs.innerHTML = figures;

  svg.appendChild(defs);

  /* получаем список всех фигур */
  var figuresAll = Array.from(defs.children);

  /* Располагаем элементы `use` (клоны) по полотну `SVG` 
  случайным образом, генерирую случайный `scale` и `rotate`. */
  for (var figure of figuresAll) {

    /* вычисляем количество фигур для конкретного шаблона */
    var number = (space * figure.getAttribute("density")) / (100 * 100);

    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      var use = document.createElement("use");

      var x = random(0, width);
      var y = random(0, height);
      use.setAttribute("x", x);
      use.setAttribute("y", y);
      use.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#" + figure.id);
      use.setAttribute("stroke", color);
      use.setAttribute("fill", "transparent");

      var rotate = random(-12, 12);
      var scale = randomFloat(0.8, 1.6);
      use.setAttribute("transform", `scale(${scale}) rotate(${rotate})`);

      svg.appendChild(use);
    }
  }

  SetSVGBackground(svg, element);
}

/* Вставляем SVG как inline фон для блока */
function SetSVGBackground(svg, element) {
  var svgCode = svg.outerHTML.replace(/\"/g, "'").replace(/\n/g, "");
  var backURL = `url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8, ${svgCode}")`;

  element.style.background = backURL;
}

/* генерируем случайное целое число */
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

/* генерируем случайное число дробного значения */
function randomFloat(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

/* Получаем из строки цвета CSS R,G и B компоненты */
function GetComponentsFromRGB(colorString) {
  var matches = colorString.match(/[0-9]+/g);
  return [+matches[0], +matches[1], +matches[2]];
}

/* Вычисляем слабо контрасный цвет для контуров фигур */
function MoveColor(colorString) {
  var components = GetComponentsFromRGB(colorString);

  var hsl = rgbToHsl(components[0], components[1], components[2]);

  var h = (hsl[0] * 360 + 20) % 360;
  var s = hsl[1] * 100;
  var l = (hsl[2] * 100 + 10);

  if (l > 100) l = 100;

  var rez = `hsl(${Math.floor(h)},${Math.floor(s)}%,${Math.floor(l)}%)`;

  return rez;
}

/* переводим цвет в формат HTL */
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
  r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
  var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
    min = Math.min(r, g, b);
  var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

  if (max == min) {
    h = s = 0; // achromatic
  } else {
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
    switch (max) {
      case r:
        h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
        break;
      case g:
        h = (b - r) / d + 2;
        break;
      case b:
        h = (r - g) / d + 4;
        break;
    }
    h /= 6;
  }

  return [h, s, l];
}

/* запускаем */
GenerateBack("d1", figures);
GenerateBack("d2", figures);
GenerateBack("d3", figures);
```

```css
#d1 {
  background-color: blanchedalmond
}

#d2 {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white
}

#d3 {
  background-color: green;
  color: white
}

.d {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1" class="d">
  <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p> Равным образом, разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии, рациональное мышление выявляет срочную потребность анализа существующих паттернов поведения. Господа, высокотехнологичная концепция общественного уклада прекрасно подходит для реализации позиций,
    занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Но стремящиеся вытеснить традиционное производство, нанотехнологии могут быть своевременно верифицированы.</p>
  <p>Непосредственные участники технического прогресса смешаны с неуникальными данными до степени совершенной неузнаваемости, из-за чего возрастает их статус бесполезности. Сложно сказать, почему акционеры крупнейших компаний, превозмогая сложившуюся непростую
    экономическую ситуацию, подвергнуты целой серии независимых исследований.</p>
</div>

<div id="d2" class="d">
  <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p> Равным образом, разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии, рациональное мышление выявляет срочную потребность анализа существующих паттернов поведения. Господа, высокотехнологичная концепция общественного уклада прекрасно подходит для реализации позиций,
    занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Но стремящиеся вытеснить традиционное производство, нанотехнологии могут быть своевременно верифицированы.</p>
  <p> С учетом сложившейся международной обстановки, начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции требует определения и уточнения существующих финансовых и административных условий. Кстати, сделанные на базе интернет-аналитики выводы указаны как претенденты на роль ключевых факторов.</p>
</div>

<div id="d3" class="d">
  <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p> Равным образом, разбавленное изрядной долей эмпатии, рациональное мышление выявляет срочную потребность анализа существующих паттернов поведения. Господа, высокотехнологичная концепция общественного уклада прекрасно подходит для реализации позиций,
    занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Но стремящиеся вытеснить традиционное производство, нанотехнологии могут быть своевременно верифицированы.</p>
  <p> С учетом сложившейся международной обстановки, начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции требует определения и уточнения существующих финансовых и административных условий. Кстати, сделанные на базе интернет-аналитики выводы указаны как претенденты на роль ключевых факторов.</p>
</div>
```

Скрипт после подключения на сайт легко вызывается.

```
GenerateBack("blockId", figures);
```

`figures` - текстовое задание фигур SVG - шаблонов для генерации.

Так как результирующий `SVG` вставляется за место фона блока, существующая разметка не ломается.

Что можно ещё улучшить:

- Сделать перерисовку при масштабировании
- Анимировать фигуры, движение по путям
- Сделать так что бы фигуры не пересекались

Попробую эти функции реализовать в новой версии скрипта.